# can't complete this action

Tags: 2010

I have sp 2010, I want to import and export sub site in the same site collection, but the import through error

**Application error when access /layouts/14/newsbweb.aspx Can't complete this action**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1: Export your subsite by using the Export-SPWeb command.**

You can do this on your SharePoint Server and run the command using the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell.  For this sample I had used the following command

> Export-SPWeb -Identity "http://someURL/SomeTeamSite/sandbox/" -Path "C:\Exported Sub Site\SandboxSubsSite.cmp" -IncludeUserSecurity -IncludeVersions all

What that command does is basically export the sub site to a .cmp file where we included all Security Settings and Versions for more options check out Export-SPWeb on TechNet

You will notice once it exports you will have a log file showing you whats been done during the export process.

[image]

**Step 2: Create you site collection.  This is where you will host your new site.**

Still on the Sharepoint Server (you can also do this remotely), go to “SharePoint 2010 Central Administration” then into “Application Management” then “Site Collections” then “Create a Site Collection”.

[image]

Indicate all of the properties needed

[image]

Take note you can also create managed paths, which means you can create a site at a specific path. To do that click on “Define Manage Paths” under the “Web Site Address”.

[image]

Once everything is set up properly you will receive a confirmation that your site collection was created.

[image]

**Step 3: Import your Content Migration Package (CMP) file that you exported using Import-SPWeb.**

Still in the Sharepoint Server using the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell issue the Import-SPWeb command, for this sample it would be something like this

> Import-SPWeb "http://someURL/sites/Sandbox" –Path "C:\Exported Sub Site\SandboxSubsSite.cmp"

Like Export-SPWeb the [Import-SPWeb can have several parameters which you can see on TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx)

[image]

It will also create an Import log and once the import finishes your all good to go.

Now check your new site collection and compare to the sub site, and if your happy feel free to remove the subsite.

**Try this, I hope this will work**